# Where do I add command line arguments to my command line tool project in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'd like to be able to pass some command line arguments to my command line tool program in Xcode. Where do I add these? I'd like to do it in the IDE rather than simply do it manually from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this in the help file:

> Running Your Application with Arguments
>
> Configure a scheme with runtime arguments for your application when
>   you run it in Xcode. The Run action in the scheme editing dialog
>   determines what happens when you choose Product > Run.
>
> From the Scheme toolbar menu, choose a scheme.
>
> From the same menu, choose Edit Scheme to display the scheme dialog.
>
> In the left column, select Run.
>
> To specify runtime arguments, click Arguments and then click the Add
>   button.
>
> Click OK.
>
> Click the Run button or choose Product > Run.

Solved my problem :-)