# Pass Variable and read in xCode , attach to string

Tags: xcode

So i am trying to do this:

I have s simple Max OS X App with just one Window and a Web View on it that opens a Website, this shall be a Web App Service later, but for now i need this:

I want to be able to pass a variable on App Launch like

```
Query.app searchword=xcode
```

the search word shall be read in Xcode and append to the URL i set to my WebView to open an URL like this:

```
www.example.com?query=[searchkey]
```

I already tried with environmental Variables or similar but they are all undefined in Xcode on Runtime

How can i do such stuff?

Is this possible?

What to search for, what kind of Method is this to google for?

thx for help

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488843/where-do-i-add-command-line-arguments-to-my-command-line-tool-project-in-xcode

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't explain anything, these steps i did already, i set an environment variable with a value but how can i read this value in the .m file to pass it to the UIWebView?